# Download my pdf in a loop through HTML2PDF

Tags: php, pdf, xhtml2pdf

I would like to download all the pdfs contained in my database through this loop.
When I click the button only the first file is downloaded.

```
<?php
include_once('functions/functions.php');
require_once('../invoice/html2pdf.class.php');
if (isset($_GET['download'])) {
    if ($_GET['download'] == 'all') {
        $req = sql_query("SELECT * FROM invoice");
        $content = ''; 
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req)) {

            $html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr');
            $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
            $content = $res['content']; 
            $html2pdf->writeHTML($content);
            ob_end_clean();
            $html2pdf->Output('' . $res['date'] . '-' . $res['user'] . '.pdf', 'D');
        }
    }
}
?>
<panel class="panel panel-flat">
    <a href="invoice?download=all">Télécharger toutes les factures</a>
</panel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only offer 1 file per download.

You can of course add them all to a zip archive, and offer that for download.

Comment: The old fashioned way: by reading the docs. :-) http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php